# How can I apply the outlines and curves of a font to a logo?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, fonts, illustration

I'm playing with a logo and I'd like to be able to use the font outlines to create the basic symbol. For example, I'm trying to create new leaf utilizing a slab serif font.

What is the best way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type > Create Outlines will create the paths for the text characters.